# Are two outputs of a PRF computationally indistinguishable when using two different keys?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, distinguisher

Assume we have a pseudorandom function $f(\cdot)$ that maps an input to $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a large prime number.

Assume $r_1$ and $r_2$ output of the pseudorandom function using two different keys.

**Question**: Are $r_1$ and $r_2$ computationally indistinguishable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Computational indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_indistinguishability) is transitive, the proof can be found [in these lecture notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/lec4.pdf). Informally speaking:

We have an advantage $\epsilon_1$ to distinguish distributions $X$ and $Y$, and we have an advantage $\epsilon_2$ to distinguish distibutions $Y$ and $Z$, and the triangle inequality gives us an advantage $\leq \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ to distinguish $X$ and $Z$. Since both $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are negligible (to be more precise, negligible functions in some security parameter), their sum $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$is also negligible.

For a pseudorandom function we know that it's indistinguishable from a random function, which is just a uniform distribution for every possible input. So both functions are indistinguishable from the same distribution, and by transitivity we get that they $f_{k_1}(.)$ and $f_{k_2}(.)$ are also indistinguishable.

---

Edit: This is only true for independent keys, thanks to Yehuda Lindell for pointing this out. The question states "different keys", which might not fulfill this requirement.

If you have dependent keys, then indistinguishability does not necessarily hold. Specifically, let $F$ be a pseudorandom function. Define $F'$ as follows: if the key $k$ is even then define $F'_k(x)=F_k(x)$; else, if $k$ is odd, then define $F'_k(x)=F_{k+1}(x)$. It is possible to prove formally (by reduction) that if $F$ is a pseudorandom function then so is $F'$. Now, consider the case that you are given $k_1,k_2$ with $k_2= k_1 + 1$. Then, with probability $1/2$ it holds that $k_1$ is even. In this case, it follows that $F'_{k_1}(x)=F'_{k_2}(x)$. Thus, $F'_{k_1}(x)\|F'_{k_2}(x)$ is not a pseudorandom string.

Under some related-key assumptions you could prove something, but this isn't standard. It's also probably beyond the scope of this question anyway.

Comment: This is only correct for *independent* keys. If they are not independent (and are just "different") then you cannot prove this. Furthermore, it's easy to come up with a counter-example.

Comment: ... but I still assume it's the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @YehudaLindell "Furthermore, it's easy to come up with a counter-example", counter example for which case? for the independent key ?

Comment: Counterexample fora different but not independent key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I agree that this is the answer but please emphasize that the keys must be independently chosen.

Comment: @YehudaLindell I also voted up your comment of course, it's just that I don't want anybody to vote down or dismiss the answer because of the comment. Sorry about the confusion, which I was actually trying to avoid by commenting in the first place.

Comment: @YehudaLindell thanks for your comment, you are right about the indistinguishability of course. I edited the answer to reflect that, but feel free to edit in your counter example if you want.